# Expectation of a constant matrix multiplied with a random vector and its transpose?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, expected-value, multivariate-normal-distribution

It is given that a random vector $\mathbf{y} \sim N(\mathbf{0}, \boldsymbol{\Theta})$, and $\mathbf{A}$ is a constant matrix. Assuming that the dimensions are compatible, what would $$E(\mathbf{A} \mathbf{y} \mathbf{y}^T)$$ equal?

I understand that $E(\mathbf{A} \mathbf{y}) = \mathbf{A} E(\mathbf{y})$ and that $E(\mathbf{y} \mathbf{y}^T)$ is simply the covariance-variance matrix of the random vector. But I am unable to evaluate the above expression. Any help would be much appreciated; thanks for reading!

Comment: _I understand that_ $E(\mathbf{A} \mathbf{y}) = \mathbf{A} E(\mathbf{y}) \mathbf{A}^T \quad\quad$No, : $Var(Ay) = A Var(y) A^T$.  Your answer below is correct.

Comment: You're right, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the expression evaluates to $$\mathbf{A} E(\mathbf{y} \mathbf{y}^T),$$ which is just $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{\Theta}$.

Comment: This is an example of linearity of the expectation operator.